# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment (Передача аргументов)

Tags: python, python-3.x

появилась у меня проблема делал вот зашифровку букв в массиве, но вылезла ошибка. В названии темы.

**Как мне можно исправить ошибку?**

```
Words = ["Шифрование", "Оранжевый", "Программирование"]
def encrypt_word(string, x):
        string[x] = string[x].replace('и', '*').replace('о','*').replace('а', '*').  replace('р', '*').replace('е', '*').replace('я', '*').replace('к', '*').           replace('т', '*').replace('ь', '*').replace('ъ', '*')
        return string[x]
    
def encrypt_range():
    for y in range(0, max_second):
        encrypt_word(Words[y], y)
```

Comment: Строки - неизменяемый тип. Нельзя просто взять, и заменить какой-то символ по индексу на другой.

Answer (score 2):

Я не очень понял реализацию требований автора в коде, но, думаю, что это автору поможет:

Замените `string[x] = string[x].replace(...)` на `string = string.replace(...)`

```
Words = ["Шифрование", "Оранжевый", "Программирование"]


def encrypt_word(string, x):
        string = string.replace('и', '*').replace('о','*').replace('а', '*').replace('р', '*').replace('е', '*').replace('я', '*').replace('к', '*').replace('т', '*').replace('ь', '*').replace('ъ', '*')
        return string
    
def encrypt_range():
    for y in range(len(Words)):
        print(encrypt_word(Words[y], y))


encrypt_range()
```

Вывод:

```
Ш*ф**в*н**
О**нж*вый
П**г**мм***в*н**
```

Comment: В ответе Tehnorobot когда я убрал 
этой строке print(encrypt_word(Words[y], y)) слово print, оно просто не зашифровывается.

Answer (score 1):

```py
words = ["Шифрование", "Оранжевый", "Программирование"]

def encrypt_word(string):
  enc = {
            'и': '*',
            'о': '*',
            'а': '*',
            'р': '*',
            'е': '*',
            'я': '*',
            'к': '*',
            'т': '*',
            'т': '*',
            'ь': '*',
            'ъ': '*'
        }
  return ''.join(enc.get(x, x) for x in string)
print(*map(encrypt_word, words), sep='\n')
# Ш*ф**в*н**
# О**нж*вый
# П**г**мм***в*н**
```

Answer (score 0):

insolor правильно сказал. Символы строки нельзя так просто изменить. Если вам нужно заменить элемент с индексом **x**, то, думаю, такой код подойдёт:

```
a = 'abcd'
x = 1
a = a[:x] + '1' + a[x + 1:]
print(a)
```